# llc: Too many positional arguments specified (error generating assembly from llvm-ir)

Tags: assembly, llvm, llvm-ir

I am getting an error with `llc` for llvm, which I just installed on my Mac with HomeBrew.

```
$ llc –o malloc.s malloc.ll
llc: Too many positional arguments specified!
Can specify at most 1 positional arguments: See: llc --help
```

I have generated a malloc.ll file like this:

```
$ clang -emit-llvm -S malloc.c -o malloc.ll
```

How do I set this up to emit assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `llc --help` output says to use `-o=<filename>`, not two separate args like `-o` and `filename`.

So when parsing its command line, it sees two options that don't start with `-`: `malloc.s` and `malloc.ll`, and complains about the situation.  Presumably they're rolling their own command line handling instead of using getopt, or they intentionally don't want to support the style where the following arg is consumed by an arg like `-o`.

Comment: (This behaviour seems surprising to me, too; enough so that it seemed worth answering.  Especially since the resulting error message should be easy to google on.)